# How can I perform arithmetic on IPy IP addresses?

Tags: python, ip-address

Using the [IPy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/IPy/) module, how can I perform arithmetic on IP addresses? That is, some function that can do the following:

```
>>> addIp(IPy.IP('10.0.0.0'), 2)
IP('10.0.0.2')
>>> addIp(IPy.IP('10.0.0.255'), 2)
IP('10.0.1.1')
```

The `IP` type does have an `__add__` method, but it is used for creating ranges out of two IP addresses.

I know doing this seems weird; my use case is iterating through IP ranges, and I'd prefer to do this without having to implement my own base-256 adder.

Comment: Why not just make use of the fact that `IPy` supports ranges that are iterable? `for ip in IP('127.0.0.0/30'): print ip`

Comment: @LukasGraf because I want to iterate IPs non-consecutively, e.g. 127.0.0.0, 127.0.0.16, 127.0.0.32...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that IP addresses are just fancy integers, and perform regular integer arithmetic and convert the result back to an IP address.

Using IPy, you can get the underlying integer representation using `.int()`. To convert an integer to an IP address, there's the function `intToIp(ip, version)` which returns an IP string; note that it will throw `ValueError` if the result is outside the valid range.

So to implement the `addIp()` function you want:

```
def addIp(ip, value):
    return IPy.IP(intToIp(ip.int() + value, ip.version()))

>>> IPy.IP(IPy.intToIp(IPy.IP('10.0.0.255').int() + 2, 4))
IP('10.0.1.1')
```